# VTK Qt Widget throwing runtime errors when placed in a GUI

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to use the VTK widget with QT. I placed it in a .ui file, and even though I did nothing else to it, I get this error when I run the program:

```
ERROR: In /build/buildd/vtk-5.8.0/Filtering/vtkImageData.cxx, line 1491
vtkImageData (0x14d0d40): SetScalarType called with no executive producing this image data object.

ERROR: In [...]/VTK/Common/Core/vtkObject.cxx, line 156
vtkObject (0x14d0d40): Trying to delete object with non-zero reference count.

Generic Warning: In [...]/VTK/Common/Core/vtkObjectBase.cxx, line 93
Trying to delete object with non-zero reference count.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried renaming the .../VTK/ folder so that no such folder exists, but it still gives the same error. Also I'm using VTK 7.0.0, so I'm not sure why I would be getting the /build/buildd/vtk-5.8.0/ error, another folder that does not exist.

The segmentation faults comes if I try to click where the widget would be.

I'm using Qt Creator 2.5.0 based on Qt 4.8.1 (64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was eventually fixed by reinstalling several things until it worked. My leading theory is that OpenCV was the culprit as it was built before I had VTK or QT and didn't have any of those flags set.